# column-count not splitting on short columns in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout, column-count

**EDIT: I've removed the `<br>` tags that several people pointed out may be causing the issue and recreated the same layout with more correct CSS, which I've included below (using `width:100%` on the labels instead of a break), but am still getting the same bug.**

I'm using `column-count:2` to put some grouped lists into columns.

It's not very often I get to write this, but on IE it works as expected, all the grouped lists split into 2 columns.

On Chrome, however, it's not splitting on a very short group of just two options. Why is this?

**IE version, working as expected**

[image: IE working as expected]

**Chrome not splitting the first, short group into 2 columns**

[image: Chrome not splitting the first, short group into 2 columns]

```css
.aoi {
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
}

.bfsubs_option_label {
background: url(checkbox_bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 0 1.75em;
height: 18px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: .5em;
background-position: 0 2px;
width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="aoi types-of-communication" style="">
  <input name="option_19807" id="option_19807" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" checked="" data-sub-id="19807">
  <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_19807">Event Invitations</label>
  <input name="option_20000" id="option_20000" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" data-sub-id="20000">
  <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_20000">Insights</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is there a `<br>` after second label?

Comment: @caramba So that I could include a right aligned background image after the label text, and still have a gap underneath. If I set it to `display:inline-block` without the break, the label merges with the next line, and if I used `display:block`, the background image is all the way to the right hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would simply change the HTML structure to wrap label/input inside divs:

```css
.aoi {
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="aoi types-of-communication">
  <div>
    <input name="option_19807" id="option_19807" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" checked="" data-sub-id="19807">
    <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_19807">Event Invitations</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="option_20000" id="option_20000" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" data-sub-id="20000">
    <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_20000">Insights</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

With more inputs:

```css
.aoi {
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="aoi types-of-communication">
  <div>
    <input name="option_19807" id="option_19807" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" checked="" data-sub-id="19807">
    <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_19807">Event Invitations</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="option_20000" id="option_20000" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" data-sub-id="20000">
    <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_20000">Insights</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="option_19807" id="option_19807" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" checked="" data-sub-id="19807">
    <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_19807">Event Invitations</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="option_20000" id="option_20000" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" data-sub-id="20000">
    <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_20000">Insights</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="option_20000" id="option_20000" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" data-sub-id="20000">
    <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_20000">Insights</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Will award the bounty when I can in 23 hours.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughs on that:

- I've been reading in another thread that on Chrome there's some weird behaviour with two columns and `column-count`. To fix that, add `break-inside: avoid-column;`

  Reference: [Chrome columns bug when number of columns is less then column-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296604/chrome-columns-bug-when-number-of-columns-is-less-then-column-count)

  Another thread suggests to additionally add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`
- Try adding `-webkit-column-count` property for Chrome. (However, I would've thought it works without):

  ```
  div {
      -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
      column-count: 3;
  }
  ```

Let me know if that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

a workaround, you can add `display: flex;` in `.aoi` and it'll work.

```css
.aoi {
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="aoi types-of-communication" style="">
  <input name="option_19807" id="option_19807" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" checked="" data-sub-id="19807">
  <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_19807">Event Invitations</label><br>
  <input name="option_20000" id="option_20000" type="checkbox" class="bfsubs_option" data-sub-id="20000">
  <label class="bfsubs_option_label" for="option_20000">Insights</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work - all the other elements from longer lists then are laid out as if they're `float:left`.